# Parsing a XML file having many or 1 tags

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I am facing issue while parsing a file for xml tags, the problem is the file can have many xml tags or it may have a single. I have tried doing it by regular expression and by using LibXML. The problem with regular expression is if there are two close ended tags on the same line my expression even prints the data between the start of the 1st tag till the end of 2nd closing tag

xml file -

```
She outsprinted Becky Smith and Joan Hare to the line, with Becky and Joan
finishing in a time of <time>1:02:41</time> and <time>  1:02:45</time>
respectively.
```

Regular expression that I am using (want to pull time details) -

```
   if (/<time>(.*)<\/time>/) {
    ($hh, $mm, $ss) = split(':', $1);
    say "Time Entered - ", $hh, ":", $mm, ":", $ss, " ";
    print "***$1***\n";
    }
```

Output

```
Time Entered - 1:02:41</time> and <time>  1
```

Expected -

```
1:02:41
1:02:45
```

** 2nd Approach - With LibXML **
I tried with this below code but it gives me an error saying

```
"KnoxHalfResults:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
Jim Colatis won Tuesday's Knoxville half marathon in a blistering pace"
```

Input file has this data-

```
Jim Colatis won Tuesday's Knoxville half marathon in a blistering pace 
of <time>   0:56:45   </time>. He was followed to the line by long time nemesis 
Mickey Mouse in a time of <time>0:58:49</time>.

my code for LibXML -
use warnings;
#use XML::Twig;
use XML::LibXML;

my $filein;
my $fileout;

($filein, $fileout) = @ARGV;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file($filein);

for my $sample ($xmldoc->findnodes('/time')) {

print $sample->nodeName(), ": ", $sample->textContent(), "\n";

}
```

Comment: Contrary to your claims, that's not an XML file, which is why libxml is complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, slurping your file and matching the patterns with regular expression.

**Note**: I recommend using a parser rather than regular expression!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "failed: $!";
my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

while ( $data =~ /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/g ) {
     print "Time Entered - $1 ***$1***\n";
}
```

Or with matching your tags

```
while ( $data =~ /<time>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/time>/g ) {
     print "Time Entered - $1 ***$1***\n";
}
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/59768)

Output

```
Time Entered - 1:02:41 ***1:02:41***
Time Entered - 1:02:45 ***1:02:45***
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the data is not XML, so you can't use an XML parser.

Is there any way to make it well-formed XML? It may be enough to wrap it in a dummy root tag and then use your XML::LibXML (or XML::Twig ;--) code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use File::Slurp;

my ($filein, $fileout) = @ARGV;

my @times;

my $t= XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { time => sub { push @times, $_->text; } })
                ->parse( '<dummy>' . read_file( $filein) . '</dummy>');

print "$_\n" foreach @times;
```

You have to be sure that the text in the file is proper XML text though. It should not include `<` or `&` that are not part of the markup.

Comment: there is no saying about the data in the file. So I have to assume that it may or may not come with proper tags.